# Consent is required to transfer ownership of a file to another user [Google Drive API]

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I have a Google Sheets file shared with 1 user - owner (Gmail account) and 2nd user - writer (google service account like @iam.gserviceaccount.com).

I use this function to copy a table from user 1 by user 2 and make the owner of copied file user 1 again:

```
$ownerPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission([
'type'         => 'user', 
'role'         => 'owner',
'emailAddress' => 'user1@gmail.com'
]);
$requestOwnership = $service->permissions->create($newfileId, $ownerPermission, ['fields' => 'id', 'transferOwnership' => 'true']);
```

And all works well until yesterday! Now Gooogle Drive API returns error: Consent is required to transfer ownership of a file to another user

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to transfer the ownership of the same file? Please take into account the fact [that](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create): `transferOwnership - Whether to transfer ownership to the specified user and downgrade the current owner to a writer.`

Comment: Yes! Google Service Account copy file (and become his owner), and then downgrades to writer.

Comment: So after this operation, you are just a writer to the file, correct? And afterwards are you trying to change ownership for you to become the owner again? If that is the case, you will have to execute the request on behalf of the service account which is the new owner after the first request. Can you provide more details?

Comment: See this image of rights in initial file https://imgur.com/a/IoN3m2q (user_1, user_2). Then I make a copy of this File by user_2 (GSA) via `$service->files->copy($originFileId, $copiedFile);` (in this step user_2 owner of copied file), after that I need change back: make user_1 owner.

Comment: I have the same issue in a slightly different scenario: a service account creates a spreadsheet and then transfers ownership to my personal account. It used to work until yesterday but now I'm getting an error 403 "Consent is required to transfer ownership of a file to another user."

Comment: Does it seem that Google has changed something? I have a code that worked almost for a year and stopped working a week ago...

Comment: My solution was change 'role'  => 'owner' to writer. Dont know why google not allow owner anymore.

Comment: Facing the same issue. @skywind did you set transferOwnership as true when changing role to writer? And on user1@gmail.com, are you able to accept the owner permission via the API?

Comment: I remove  transferOwnership when change role to writer. How to accept ownership by user1 I not found(

Comment: *remove transferOwnership parametr

Comment: Also have a script which has been working fine for years, suddenly giving this error. Must have been a change Google's side.
Use case: create spreadsheet under service account and share to a personal account trying to set them as an owner

Comment: To @ht96 and others: I have a similar use case to create a file (spreadsheet) under a google service account but have the file visible and accessible by a regular gmail account. It might be an idea to create a folder in drive as the gmail account and share Editor rights to the service account. Service account can then create the file in drive of gmail account. This approach has been working for me.

Comment: @DJoyce AFAIK, The files owned by service accounts (SA) will be deleted when these accounts (SAs) are deleted. Sharing folders with SAs might not be safe, as files could suddenly be deleted when the SA is deleted.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a recent change to the google API.  See also https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-sharing

I haven't tried this, but it suggests that you should replace transferOwnership=true with role=writer and pendingOwner=true, and then separately update the permissions as user1@gmail.com with role=owner.  I don't know how you do that second step from a gmail.com account though.

Comment: After `drive_service.permissions().update(...` transferOwnership=true with role=writer and pendingOwner=true — it will ask the ownership receiver to accept the ownership to continue.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working as expected as according to this Issue Tracker issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228826345):

> Following up here, this is the expected behavior as currently Drive does not support the changing of the ownership for items which are owned by gmail.com accounts.

Comment: can not open this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227973724#comment22
Access denied for: gia@gss.ge
Access denied for: chipintoza@gmail.com
on both my account

Comment: This is happening on Spreadsheet share functionality too. I assume that link is an internal google access only?

Comment: I have edited the link!