# error it has been flagged as inappropriate gdrive v3 api transfer ownership

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a folder in my Google Drive using service account.

After folder been created, I'm trying to transfer ownership to my email because by creating using service account, the folder cannot be directly seen in the Google Drive

But I have received this error

```
 code: 400,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Bad Request. User message: "You cannot share this item because it has been flagged as inappropriate."',   
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'invalidSharingRequest'
    }
  ]
```

below is the code

```
const { google} = require('googleapis');
const credentials = require('./key.json')

const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']

const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
    credentials.client_email,
     null,
    credentials.private_key,
     scopes
);
const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });



const createFold = async (fold) => {
    const fileMetaData = {
        name: fold,
        mimeType: "application/vnd.google-apps.folder",
    };
    const response =await drive.files
        .create({
            fields: "id",
            resource: fileMetaData,
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    const foldId = response.data.id;
    const resp = await drive.permissions
        .create({
            resource: {
                type: "user",
                role: "owner",
                emailAddress: "koko$$$$@gmail.com", //example google email
            },
            fileId: foldId,
            fields: "id",
            moveToNewOwnersRoot: true,
            transferOwnership: true,
            
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};

createFold('myFiles')
```

Comment: Hi, Kindly provide a minimal reproducible example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) such as the authentication code you're using so people can easily replicate your setup.

Comment: @ShadowReaper updated the code. tq

Comment: We are trying to replicate the code you have provided but we are getting an error in the `drive.files.create` on `fields: "id"` where it returns an undefined response value related to this error `ENETUNREACH`. Is there anything else not included in your code?

Comment: @ShadowReaper change `fields:id` and add drive and using above code still get same error. even adding `pendingOwner:true` from this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71749779/consent-is-required-to-transfer-ownership-of-a-file-to-another-user-google-driv) received the same error